# Sudden drop in Neural Network loss

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am practicing on predicting house prices for https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/overview.

I am experiencing a very sudden drop in loss at a certain point of training. The graph looks like this:
[image: Graph1]

Which at first made me thing the **learning rate** is *too low*, but when I zoom in after the drop:

[image: Graph2]

it seems that it is *too high* (and there is overfitting as well?).

The **NN** I chose is (using PyTorch)

```py
net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(331, 96),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(96, 8),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(8, 1)
)
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening? Can it have something to do with custom loss function I use (I tried sort-of "relative fraction loss")?

```py
def my_loss(y_hat, y):
    frac = (y_hat - y) / y
    return torch.abs(frac)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, since the drop is pretty steep... but my best guess would be at the loss function as well.

You see, the fuction you wrote has very different landscapes for values lesser than your goal or values greater than your goal.

Let's say my goal is 200k.

If I miss the target by 190k below, guessing 10k, my loss would be at |(200k-10k)/10k| = 19;

If I miss the target by 190k above, guessing 390k, my loss would be at |(200k-390k)/390k| = 0.48;

[You can see that graphicaly here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28200000-x%29%2Fx+%2C+from+0+to+400000)

So, my guess would be that around the epoch 90 your network switched from very low to very high guesses. Not necessarily better guesses, but guesses with waaay lower losses nonetheless.

Comment: the function divides by **label**, so both **|(10k-200k) / 200k|** and **|(390k-200k) / 200k|** give .95 loss

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a definitive solution to this problem:

You should do data preprocessing.

and you will definitely see that its data is not balanced and is accumulating somewhere.

If your data has outliers, you may need to delete most of the data you have.

Here is a tip for data preprocessing:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-preprocessing-in-data-mining/